# How to set bigger text into textview with width wrap_content?

Tags: android, textview, width, settext

I have `listview`. Each it's element has `date` (`Calendar` object), so I want to display current date at top visible element. I have `implemented ListView.OnScrollListener`

```
public  void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        int index = firstVisibleItem;
        if (index < eventsList.size() && eventsList.size() > 0){
            Event ev = eventsList.get(index);
            setTitleDate(ev.getCalendar()); 

        } 
}
```

`Event` is my own `class`, `getCalendar()` returns `Calendar` object, `eventsList` is `arraylist` of `Event` objects.

Here is `setTitleDate` function:

```
protected void setTitleDate(Calendar cc){
    dateFormatTopDateWithWeekday = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM");
    topDate.setText(dateFormatTopDateWithWeekday.format( cc.getTime() ).toUpperCase());
}
```

`topDate` is a `textview`:

```
topDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.event_top_date);
```

And a part of my template:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cat_top_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/main_top_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/header_title"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:typeface="normal" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_top_date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/cat_top_name"
                        android:text="@string/main_top_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/header_title"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:typeface="normal"
                         />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

`event_top_date textview` has width `wrap_content`, so when I set text dynamically in `setTitleDate` and if `width` of new text is bigger, the width of textview does not become bigger and text is clipped.
I don't know why `wrap_content` does not work.

[image]

So I have tried such a variants:

1. `gravity fill` in text view
2. `topDate.setLayoutParams(new
       LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

but it didn't help.

Comment: did u try invalidate() after setting the new text?

Comment: invalidate on your layout not just text view?

Comment: I see two text views are placed one below the other. then y ur relative orientation is horizontal?

Comment: it doesn't matter what orientation in relative layout

Answer (score 1):

use this line in your textview

android:singleLine="true"

Comment: for first textview specify  android:layout_width="60dp" for second textview use fill_parent.

Comment: I think you can use wrap_content for first text view but it needs to be fill_parent for second.

Comment: please share screenshot what u want exactly

Comment: on my screenshot you can see two screens.
on second i set text "THURSDAY, 20 DECEMBER", but it is bigger than it was at first : "СЕГОДНЯ, 20 DECEMBER" and "DECEMBER" is clipped.
i need to set the whole date.

Comment: Did u try changing the orientation to vertical? and then layout_width of textview to match_parent?

Comment: for second textview (android:id="@+id/event_top_date") change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: i cant set fill_parent or match_parent, because i also want  set the second textview in center horizontal:
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: Why is ur orientation horizontal?

Comment: i have already said, that i cant set width fill_parent, because of android:layout_centerHorizontal="true". also saying again, that it doesn't matter what orientation in relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_top_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="main_top_name"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_top_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cat_top_name"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="THURSDAY, 20 DECEMBER"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```